# SBT not producing jar file

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I am using SBT to manage the dependencies. The code compiles as shown below, but no jar file is generated.

Interesting part is that earlier today, SBT was generating a jar file in the /target/spark-2.1/ directory. Now its only updating the classes. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
$ sbt compile
[info] Set current project to Spark for Beginners (in build file:/tmp/Scala3/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /tmp/Scala3/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[success] Total time: 10 s, completed Mar 1, 2017 5:25:29 PM
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Did you previously call

```
sbt package
```

The compile command only compiles the sources without packaging them. See here for a list of possible sbt commands: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Combined+Pages.html#Running

Comment: Thanks, Harald. You saved the day.

Comment: You're welcome! Could you also accept the answer please?